# SQL difference between IN and JOIN

Tags: sql, join, relational-database, relational-algebra

First I need to say that it is safe to assume that I have no formal education in SQL although I have education in relational algebra.

I am investigating what would be the best approach to the following problem.

Our database is holding texts and keywords for every text.

```
Articles
id | text

Keywords
id | word

Articles_keywords
id_article | id_keyword
```

For the sake of this question the provider of answer can assume that tables are indexed however one wants.

**So the problem is getting all articles that have a specific keyword.**

I have talked with 2 groups of people that solve this in 2 ways, and they both claim that the approach of other group is wrong.

First solution using the IN operator:

```
SELECT * FROM Articles AS a WHERE a.id IN 
    (SELECT id_article FROM Articles_Keywords AS ak WHERE ak.id_keyword IN 
        (SELECT id FROM keywords AS k WHERE k.word = 'xyz'));
```

Other solution is using JOIN operator of course:

```
SELECT * FROM Articles as a 
    JOIN Articles_Keywords as ak 
        ON a.id = ak.id_article
    JOIN Keywords as k 
        ON k.id = ak.id_keyword
WHERE k.word = 'xyz';
```

Which approach is better and, above all, why?

**Edit**

In articles table we have an id column being unique and, just for the sake of this question we could assume that there are no duplicate texts.

The same thing goes for the keywords table.

In article_keywords table the ordered pair (id_article,id_keyword) is unique

Comment: What unique constraints exist on your tables?

Comment: Neither is "wrong".  I speculate that the general consensus is that the approach using `join`s is preferred because it easier to read and more flexible (you can readily get columns from any of the tables).  However, I'm voting to close because you are asking for an opinion.

Comment: I am asking what is better and of course why. It is not an opinion it is the matter of which algorithm is better in terms of time complexity.

Comment: @MartinSmith ids are unique and keywords are unique also.  in Articles_keywords the ordered pair of ids is unique

Comment: SQL is declarative. It doesn't define any algorithm. That is up to the query optimiser in the implementation. The two can return different results if there are duplicates though.

Comment: @MartinSmith we can assume for the sake of this question that there are no duplicates.

Comment: Those two queries are not doing the same thing. So the question isn't which one is better, but which one is correct. _If_ they are equivalent e.g. because `id_article` is **unique** in `Articles_Keywords` (and `id` also is unique in `keywords`) then a modern optimizer will use the same execution plan anyways.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, I was considering the scenario where those two queries are equivalent. Thank you.

Comment: 1. Please edit your clarifications into your question. 2. What does "wrong" mean in "the approach of other group is wrong"? 3. The queries return different column sets, so they are never the same result.

Comment: For *some* basis of comparison read about EXPLAIN.